# Unexpected behavior when using Dingbats with ucharclasses

Tags: xetex, ucharclasses

I'm trying to switch to and from a Dingbats font using `ucharclasses`, and I'm failing to obtain correct results. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2in,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}

\newfontfamily{\dingbatsfont}{Zapf Dingbats}

\setTransitionTo{Dingbats}{\dingbatsfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Dingbats}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
I award you a ✓︎, which is what you deserve.
\end{document}
```

Here's what I'm getting:
[image: Bad result.]

It appears that the transition from the Dingbats block isn't happening. I tried changing the `\setTransition...` code to

```
\setTransitionTo{Dingbats}{[entering dingbats] \dingbatsfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Dingbats}{\rmfamily [exiting dingbats]}
```

and obtained
[image: Another bad result.]

which seems to confirm that this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not necessarily want to switch to `\rmfamily` when you transition from a block.  The correct behavior would be to switch back to the font you were using before.  You can accomplish this by changing the font between a `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.

There are numerous bugs in `ucharclasses`: not only does the transition from Dingbats never get called, the `\setTransitions` macro documented in the manual does not exist.  However, another workaround is to set the default transitions to `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`.  The default transition out does (erroneously) get called instead.

This is really iffy, since actually enabling the character class I use breaks it.

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Show a warning for missing characters
\documentclass[border=0.2in,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}

\newfontfamily{\dingbatsfont}{DejaVu Sans}[Scale = MatchUppercase]

\setDefaultTransitions{\begingroup}{\endgroup}
\setTransitionsForSymbols{\begingroup\dingbatsfont}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\sffamily I award you a ✓︎, which is what you deserve.
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

Your patch, `\XeTeXinterchartoks \DingbatsClass 0 =`, also works here.

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % Show a warning for missing characters
\documentclass[border=0.2in,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[Dingbats]{ucharclasses}

\newfontfamily{\dingbatsfont}{DejaVu Sans}[Scale = MatchUppercase]

\setTransitionTo{Dingbats}{\begingroup\dingbatsfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Dingbats}{\endgroup}
% Workaround for a bug in ucharclasses:
\XeTeXinterchartoks \DingbatsClass 0 = {\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\sffamily I award you a ✓︎, which is what you deserve.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks; I like your solution better than mine.

Comment: Glad I could help! That’s why we ask questions.

Comment: @Derek And I learned several things from your answer. Although they should probably be reported to the package maintainer as bugs.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there isn't a current package maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `ucharclasses` doesn't fully cover this case. Apparently (as far as I can tell), switching out of Dingbats is equivalent to ending a "word", which needs to be handled as special case. The workaround is to add

```
\XeTeXinterchartoks \DingbatsClass 0 = {\rmfamily [exiting dingbats]}
```

which produces the expected result:

[image: Fixed!]